# Steema TeeBI with C++Builder

Tags: teechart

I'm trying to use Steema TeeBI Business Intelligence framework with Embarcadero C++Builder in RADStudio 10.2.2.
Converting the Delphi example in this page:
http://teechart.net/docs/teebi/tutorials/Using-the-API/

when I try to translate this line:

```
Customers['CustomerID'].Int32Data[0] := 1;
```

into this line

```
Customers["CustomerID"]->Int32Data[0] = 1; // Error
```

I encounter this error:

> E2034 Cannot convert 'char const[11]' to 'int'

But this works:

```
Customers->operator[]("CustomerID")->Int32Data[0] = 1; // OK
```

Can somebody reproduce this situation and fix this bug in Steema?
Thank you.